# Does the space of densely defined operators on a Hilbert space form a Hilbert space?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Is it possible to define an inner product/norm on the space of densely defined (closed if necessary) operators on a Hilbert space $H$, i.e., linear maps $H\rightarrow H$?

EDIT: I'm looking for a construction similar to Hilbert-Schmidt operators and their corresponding inner product.

Comment: Assuming the axiom of choice, every vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ can be equipped with an inner product. Maybe you want the inner product to have some properties, in which case you should specify them.

Comment: What is the inner product on the space of bounded linear operators that you have in mind?

Comment: "The space of bounded operators on a Hilbert space $H$ has a natural inner product so that it is (I think) isomorphic to the conjugate space $\bar{H}$." -- Not true. There is no "natural" inner product on $B(H)$, and it is not isomorphic to a Hilbert space.

Comment: Sorry, I got confused with the dual space $H^*$. I changed my question accordingly

Comment: Isn't the space of bounded linear operators on a Hilbert space that Hilbert space itself?

Comment: @herbsteinberg I think you have the same confusion as I had and you're thinking of Riesz representation theorem, but that should be for the dual space $H^*$

Comment: @Andrew Yuan  I was thinking of operators from Hilbert space to scalar field.